# When is a preposition required with a time span and when not?

Tags: preposition

Here are three sentences taken from a single podcast transcript.

> Dieses Jahr findet die neunundsechzigste Berlinale statt.
>
> Dieses Jahr findet seine letzte Berlinale statt.
>
> Jury-Präsidentin ist in diesem Jahr die französische Schauspielerin Juliette Binoche.

In the first 2 why is there no preposition introducing the time span as there is in the third, or conversely, why is "in" necessary in the third and not the first two?

Answer (score 6):

There's no evidence that *in* is really necessarry in the 1st two cases or the 3rd one.

You could as well say

> In diesem Jahr findet die neunundsechzigste Berlinale statt.
>
> In diesem Jahr findet seine letzte Berlinale statt.
>
> Jury-Präsidentin ist dieses Jahr die französische Schauspielerin Juliette Binoche.

Comment: Excellent! Very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @userunknown would be easier to read without a change of the word order, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt bei Zeitangaben auch den "**adverbialen Akkusativ**". Der ist in der Umgangssprache in meiner Region (Westdeutschland) der Normalfall:

> Ich komme nächst**en** Mittwoch.

In den beiden erstgenannten Sätzen ist "dieses Jahr" jeweils ein adverbialer Akkusativ. Das wird erst deutlich, wenn man ein männliches Substantiv einsetzt:

> Nächsten Monat findet die 69. Berlinale statt.

Fast immer kann man die adverbialen Akkusative jedoch in präpositionale Adverbialangaben umwandeln:

> "nächsten Mittwoch" = "*am nächsten Mittwoch*"